# Window load wrapper for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` is a known and great way to protect the $ from causing errors.

What I'm curious about is if `jQuery(window).load(function($){});` would work in the same way?

Basically, what I have now is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).load(function(){
       // ...
    }); 

});
```

This just seems unnecessary to me, any ideas about simplifying this? I need the safety of having jQuery properly mapped to $ (or whatever the correct term is) but the same timing as `window.load()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer this...

```
(function($){

    $(window).load(function(){
        //everything is loaded (images, scripts, etc.)
    });

    // and/or

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // the dom is in place, but everything is not necessarily loaded
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Note: This will only work if jQuery was included before this script. I have never encountered any problems with jQuery being undefined this way. Furthermore, you will never have problems with $ being undefined, because you are passing it into your anonymous function.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this:

```
(function($) {

    $(window).load(function(){
       // ...
    }); 

})(jQuery);
```

The anonymous function will be executed immediately rather than waiting for DOM ready as in the code in the question. Within the function `$` will be a reference to `jQuery` so won't clash with any other `$` defined outside the anonymous function.

Comment: I gave you one since you beat me to the answer, but your answer wasn't selected

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local parameter:

```
(function($) {
    $(...)
})(jQuery);
```

This code executes an anonymous function with a parameter named `$`, passing `jQuery` as the parameter value.